# Create rows from values with Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible with Excel formula to translate a "record" into multiple rows? Let's say I have column A and B and want to translate it to achieve values showing in column D & E
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my question. I have column A and B and want to translate it to achieve values showing in column D & E

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in D2 and copy down till you get blanks:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<=SUM(B:B),INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(ROW(A1)-1,SUMIF(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,ROW($B$2:$B$4)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$4))+1,),">0"))),"")
```

Depending on one's version, this may require the formula be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Then put this in E2 and copy down:

```
=IF(D2<>"",COUNTIFS($D$2:D2,D2),"")
```

[image]

---

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula `SEQUENCE()` then the first Formula can be replaced with:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(B:B),,0),SUMIF(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,SEQUENCE(COUNT(B:B)),),">0")))
```

Put that in D2 and Excel will spill the results down.

The second formula would become:

```
=COUNTIFS(OFFSET($G$1,1,0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D2#)),),D2#)
```

Again put that in E2 and Excel will spill down the results.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I get an #N/A error. I only replaced the comma with semicolon for my Excel version =IF(ROW(A1)<=SUM(B:B);INDEX($A$2:$A$4;MATCH(ROW(A1)-1;SUMIF(OFFSET($B$1;0;0;ROW($B$2:$B$4)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$4))+1;);">0")));"")

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: No I pressed only Enter

Comment: Click in the formula bar, then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Excel should put `{}` around the formula.  Then drag down

Comment: Perfect it worked thanks a lot. Just interested why do we need matrix formula here?

Comment: `SUMIF(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,SEQUENCE(COUNT(B:B)),),">0")` returns an array, in this case `{0,3,5}` to the MATCH, so the INDEX knows which row to use.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. I will try to understand the formula but it really works great!

Comment: Dear Scott, just another question, would it be possible to have the counting in column "E" not counting more than 4, means in your picture the current formula calculates: 1,2,3,1,2,4,5. Counting until 4 would give 1,2,3,1,2,4,1. So restarting counting when the maximum is reached. Could this be implemented without breaking the whole formula?

Comment: @cekar new questions get new posts

Comment: Ok will create a new question